# Why is my command line giving different info then visual studio when checking status of git repo?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I am testing writing a script to pull down the latest version of the master and then merge or rebase my local branch based off the updated master.

While trying to do so I am running into an issue, where visual studio is seeing that there is a commit I need to pull down to get up to date but the command line states that I am current.

I have attached a screen shot showing an incoming commit showing in Visual Studio but the cli showing up to date.

[image: Confusing displays]

[image: Repo Folder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `git status` is showing no changes in the remote (`origin/master`), but Visual Studio does show changes to pull, it might be that Git hasn't updated its remote tracking branches.  Only commands `git fetch`, `git pull`, and `git remote update` typically actually access the remote server to update its status.  This is part of what makes Git so fast -- it is normally working from the local repository.

Run `git remote update` to update the remote tracking branches.  Then `git status` will show accurately the changes to pull.

Example:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
✔ ~/myrepo [develop|✔] 
$ git remote update
Fetching origin
✔ ~/myrepo [develop ↓·1|✔] 
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
✔ ~/myrepo [develop ↓·1|✔] 
$
```

Comment: Can I use git rebase in this situation or would I want to use git pull? (My apologies for lack of knowledge.We are moving from team foundation server to git through ADO and so got thrown into the deep end as the guinea pig.)

Comment: You would only need `git rebase` if you have diverged from the remote tracking branch by making a local commit to master in addition to the remote commit.  Now be aware that `git pull` does automatically do a merge, but it's an unhelpful one and I strongly recommend that you do use `rebase` if there are divergent changes. (Set `git config --global pull.ff only`, then `git pull` will warn if there are divergent changes and you can do `git rebase origin/master` to resolve)

Comment: FYI recommendation on avoiding Git pull merges: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/handling-git-pull-automatic-merges https://coderwall.com/p/7aymfa/please-oh-please-use-git-pull-rebase